# How to exclude 0 from my query, but include null?

Tags: sql, soql

I would appreciate a little help. Values in the column are 1, 0 and null. I want to write a condition where I exclude only 0, but rows with values 1 and null are included.

I did not think this would be a problem for me, but it is.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `isnull(yourcolumn, 1) = 1` - or what is your DBMS equivalent for this.

Comment: SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE _condition_

Comment: `WHERE columnname IS DISTINCT FROM 0`, if your dbms supports the DISTINCT precidate.

Comment: In Oracle you can use nvl for this problem: nvl(column_name, 1) = 1.

Comment: NVL, ISNULL... Why not use the ANSI SQL `coalesce()`...?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
select * from tablename
where column=1 or column is null
```